# Changing the precedence of the operators in C

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

As precedence of && is more (is this the suitable adj.?) than precedence of ||, I wrote something like this:

```
if (a || b && c ){ ....
```

I guess the program will first find `b && c`, let's call it `d`, and then find `a || d`, right?

I want the the program to check "a" statement first, and then if it is wrong; check b  and c. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Precedence and order of operations are really different things.

Comment: well I thought precedence is the Word I was looking, my english is not very well. sorry for that

Comment: Succinctly, you cannot change the precedence of the operators in C — nor can you do so in C++, even though you can define operators for classes you define.  You can control the order of evaluation (to some extent, with some operators, especially `&&`, `||`, `?:` and `,`).  As it happens, what you wrote will do what you want; I'd want to write it as `if (a || (b && c))` to make it clear to other readers exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logical expressions in C are subject to [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Now, as you noted,

```
a || b && c
```

is the same as

```
a || (b && c)
```

because of precedence.

But `a` is evaluated first, because evaluation order is left-to-right. Because of short-circuit evaluation, only if `a` is false does the program then go on to evaluate `b && c`. So, your code already does what you want it to.

Comment: +1 Note: `(b && c)` should also be short-circuit evaluated. After testing `a` and receiving `false` back, if `b` is false, `c` shouldn't be evaluated. I know David knows this, but the OP may not.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the the program to check "a" statement first, and then if it is wrong; check b and c. Is something like this possible?

Yes. You are going right.

`a || b && c` will be parsed as  `a || (b && c)` because `&&` has higher precedence than that of `||` operator. `b` and `c` binds to `&&`.
As **logical operators evaluates from left to right**, first `a` is evaluated, if it is `true` then `b && c` would not be evaluated because `||` operator performs short circuit evaluation of its operand.

If `a` evaluated as `false` then `b && c` will be evaluated, in which `b` is evaluated first and on being `true` `c` is evaluated, otherwise `c` would not be evaluated because of the same reason that`&&` performs short circuit evaluation of its operand.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess the program will first find b && c, let's call it d, and then find a || d, right?

No.

First of all, operator precedence only affects grouping of operators and operands; it *does not* affect the order in which expressions are evaluated.  In general, evaluation order is left *unspecified*; for example, in an expression like `a + b * c`, each of `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated *in any order*.  Similarly, `b * c` must be evaluated before `a + b * c`, but that doesn't mean that `b * c` must be evaluated before `a`.

The `||` and `&&` operators are special in that they force left-to-right evaluation; the left-hand side will be fully evaluated (and all side effects applied) first.  Also, both operators use "short-circuit" evaluation; if the value of the expression can be determined from the left-hand operand, then the right-hand operand won't be evaluated *at all*.

Since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, the expression will be parsed as `a || (b && c)`, meaning the result of `a` will be OR'd with the result of `b && c`.  However, since `||` and `&&` force left to right evaluation, `a` will be evaluated first.  If the result of `a` is 0, then `b` will be evaluated.  If the result of `b` is non-zero, then `c` will be evaluated.  If `b` is 0, then `c` won't be evaluated.  If `a` is non-zero, then neither `b` nor `c` will be evaluated.

Here's a table showing the various possibilities; NZ means "non-zero", and NE means "not evaluated":

```
a    b    c      b && c      a || b && c
-    -    -      ------      -----------
0    NZ   NZ     true  (1)   true  (1)
0    NZ   0      false (0)   false (0)
0    0    NE     false (0)   false (0)
NZ   NE   NE     NE          true  (1)
```